# How To Implement/ Handling Exception In ExpressJs (NODE.JS)

Tags: node.js, express, exception, error-handling

Is it possible to implement the below way to handle the exception in expressjs Framework:

actually, I am calling a method ( Fun1 ) by a passing parameter (key_id, user_id). Like below:

data = Fun1(key_id=123, user_id=234)

so, if above line returns an error then I need to call other function (Fun2) otherwise no need to call this (Fun2)

I am implementing like this way, but it's not working( Means, when try block return error then catch block, is not executing)

```
try{
var data = Fun1(key_id=123, user_id=234);
}
catch(err){
var data = Fun2(key_id=123, user_id=234);
}
```

is there any other way to handle?

Comment: Define "not working" in technical terms.

Comment: @tadman can you check once

Comment: Check what? I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: this is not related to express at all. If you throw an error inside the try block, the execution continues in the catch block. Maybe Fun1 doesn't throw an error, just returns normally. Even if the returned value is an Error, or a rejected promise, it doesn't matter, since it is not thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If the Fun1 throws an error then the above mentioned implantation works perfect and moves to the catch block and executes the Fun2 but if it returns a value then this does not work

Syntax for throwing an error

```js
 throw new Error("<Error Message>")
```